# Angular i18n img alt attribute with select

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have a simple `img` (flag) with `alt` attribute that contains currency name:

```
  <img
    src="assets/flags/flag-{{ currency.country_code }}.svg"
    alt="{{ currency.name }}"
  />
```

Now I'm trying to internationalize the app.

And I want to translate the currency name in the `alt` attribute.

As I read docs, I should use `select` for this.

My code now looks like this:

```
  <img
    src="assets/flags/flag-{{ currency.country_code }}.svg"
    i18n-alt
    alt="{currency.name, select, Euro {Euro} Dollar USA {Dollar USA}}"
  />
```

And now, when I run: `ng xi18n`

I get error:

`Unexpected translation for attribute "alt" (id="61db1324f7a3d715e72771642ef672fb95ed27d9") ("`

If I try this way:

```
  <img
    src="assets/flags/flag-{{ currency.country_code }}.svg"
    i18n-alt
    [alt]="{currency.name, select, Euro {Euro} Dollar USA {Dollar USA}}"
  />
```

or this way:

```
  <img
    src="assets/flags/flag-{{ currency.country_code }}.svg"
    i18n-alt
    [alt]="currency.name, select, Euro {Euro} Dollar USA {Dollar USA}"
  />
```

I get a lot of lexer errors, like this:

`Parser Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected character [а] at column 488 in expression [{currency.name, select,`

I'm wondering to kick the i18n out and use `ngx-translate`, but, please, stop me.

Comment: I don't think this is possible https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21615

Comment: thnks, I already took a decision to switch to ngx-translate, will start on Monday =]